# List size listener in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, addeventlistener

I've created a dynamic list where the users can add stuff and remove stuff, I have a limit to this list where users can't enter more than the limit which is 5. Every time a user hit's "Enter" in input field I check if list size reached it's max to change a  text and font color as I don't want alerts. On the other hand, if the list reached it's limit and the user decided to remove some items, the issue here is how can I monitor the size of the list constantly to give better feedback. Is there a way to put an eventListener on the (ul) to check how many (li)s in it??? I'm using JQuery to manage everything, I wouldn't mind solutions from other languages.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type here">
<ul class="sortable" id="inputList">
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($serverItems); $i++)
        echo "<li>".$serverItems[$i]."<a class='close remove'>&times;</a></li>"; 
?>
</ul>
<span id="listLimit">(Max: 5)</span>
```

My JQuery will look something like this:

```
$('#input').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val()!="") {
        if($('#inputList li').size()<5){
        var item = $(this).val();
        $('#inputList').append('<li>' + item + '<a class="close remove">&times;</a></li>');
        } else $('#listLimit').text('Maximum Limit Reached!').css('color','red');
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

And this is how I remove an item on click:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Note that class 'close' is just for CSS, class 'remove' is what's called in JQuery to remove the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below option

```
        $("li").on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

In your keydown function check for the count of li items by $( "li" ).length 
Total Count of li items 
alert( "Size: " + $( "li" ).length );
Note: .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8,better use .length() in place of size()

Other syntax error which i have observed is #input is for the input field with id -input but in your example there is no id for input, so it should be as below

$('input').keydown(function(e)

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKKoYx

Comment: Thank you I've added the limit to the parent's title so I can retrieve it, this is what I got: $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
if($(this).parent().parent().children('li').length==parseInt($(this).parent().parent().attr('title')))
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children('span').text('(Max: '+$(this).parent().parent().attr('title')+')').css('color','black');
$(this).parent().remove();
}); That's how I changed the text back to normal (black) with the limit

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change two code ..

1. $('#input') change to $('input') => input is not id just element
2. don't use `.size()` it is deprecated ,use instead `.length`

Comment: I'm using id's because I have multiple inputs, each input deals with specific list. I changed size to length, thank you